# What is this fruits ? pingpong ball size, skin like balsam pear

Tags: fruits

I saw this on a Chinese site zhihu, auther is a fruits hunter .

[image]

He said this fruit is one of his favourites, juice smell very good , 10 times better than strawberries.

Search `金光果` in Chinese search engine give me another fruit. 
I only want to know this.

Answer (score 1):

The auther told me it named Prainea limpato .
And google image search gave me another name Kesusu .

No Wiki found .

China Natural specimen museum http://www.cfh.ac.cn/album/ShowSpAlbum.aspx?spid=6936484

Can be found at last of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2iv40GA-rlA

Comment: Fascinating. I didn't know about that one.  Here is another link. http://www.mysabah.com/wordpress/the-coolest-fruit-of-borneo/